# error: package xxx.ast.databinding does not exist import xxx.ast.databinding.DiscBinding;

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

Getting an error as below, what should I do to resolve this error.

```
D:xx\files\ExpoCastDeviceSelectFragment.java:39: error: package xxx.ast.databinding does not exist
import xxx.ast.databinding.DiscBinding;
```

DiscFragment.java :

```
import xxx.ast.databinding.DiscBinding;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DiscBinding discBinding;
        discBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.disc);

        /* Intantiate the view model */
        xView = ViewModelProviders.of(this, xViewModelFactory).get(ViewModel.class);
        xView.getViewModelState().observe(getActivity(), this);
     
        discBinding.setViewModel(mViewModel);
        discBinding.executePendingBindings();
        ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());
    
    }
```

disc.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <data>
            <variable
                name="discover"
                type="xx.ViewModel" />
        </data>
    
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/disc_dis"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
                android:background="@{discover.isEnabled ? @drawable/corner_dark : @drawable/corner_light}"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/to"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/to"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_gray_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/pd"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/disys"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_disy_item" />
    
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/disc"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_width"
                        android:indeterminate="true"
                        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/background_color"
                        android:progressTint="@color/progressbar_color"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.474"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.326" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state_message"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pd6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/element_margin"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/element_margin"
                        android:text="@string/progress_message"
                        android:textColor="@{discover.isEnabled ? @color/text_white : @color/text_black_color}"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/size"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/disc" />
    
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_error_action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pd12"
                        android:background="@color/action_btn_background"
                        android:padding="@dimen/action_btn_padding"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/state_message"
                        tools:text="@string/expo_turn_bluetooth_on_label" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </layout>


    <color name="text_white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="text_black_color">#272626</color>

corner_dark.xml : 

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
            android:topRightRadius="16dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/darktheme"></solid>
        <size android:height="48dp"/>
        <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />
    </shape>


corner_light.xml : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
            android:topRightRadius="12dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>
        <size android:height="48dp"/>
        <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not added data binding dependencies in build.gradle file so first you have to add these dependencies

**DataBinging Offical Doc - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start**

Add this way -

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

**ViewBinding Offical Doc - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding**

and I personally recommend viewbinding because easy to use rather than data binding because I am personally using viewbinding....

Comment: dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

Comment: Thanks. But your answer didn't fix my issue, since I already have databinding enabled, the issue was with the viewmodel that I included in the type for databinding. Also, since I have to change the color of the views based on user preference, I am afraid using the viewbinding, my changes would be in the fragments to change the color of the views. With databinding, those changes would be handled in the xml through the annotation.